# Facing Error while connecting to VMware VNC Console Access via HTML Console SDK

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

I'm facing a challenge with accessing the VNC Console through VMware's HTML Console SDK and would really appreciate some guidance. Here's a rundown of what I've done and the issue I'm encountering:

**Steps Taken:**

1. **Setting Up**: I've used the HTML Console SDK from VMware, which involves loading the WebMKS script into an HTML page. This setup requires jQuery, jQueryUI, access to vCenter Server and an ESXi host, a local HTTP server, and the mentioned libraries.
2. **Procedure Followed**:

- Downloaded and unzipped the HTML Console SDK.
- Created an HTML page for the console display.
- Managed security certificates for vCenter Server and ESXi host.
- Obtained a WebMKS ticket.
- Entered the ESXi host IP and the VM's WebMKS ticket in the `wmks.connect` function.
- Used the provided JavaScript sample code for the remote HTML Console.

1. **Ticket Generation**: I've used a Python script to connect to the vSphere server, locate the VM, and generate the MKS ticket.

**Current Setup and Issue**:

- The ticket generation and VM console connection code is hosted on a server (IP: xx.xxx.xxx.100).
- I'm trying to connect to a VM (IP: xx.xxx.xxx.83), which is on an ESXi host (IP: xx.xxx.xxx.80) and managed by vSphere Client (IP: xx.xxx.xxx.81).

​

*The problem: I'm getting a failed WebSocket connection with the error: 'Web socket connection wss://xx.xxx.xxx.80:902/ticket/tickerID failed.'*
Also tried 443 port as well

​

**Any advice or pointers would be highly appreciated! Also, has anyone else encountered a similar issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now. The issue was related to ticket that was created by following line in my Python Script

```
ticket = vm.AcquireMksTicket()
```

I replaced above line with the following line.

```
 ticket = vm.AcquireTicket(ticketType='webmks')
```

AcquireMksTicket only works with very old vSphere versions.